# How to position .vtt subtitles inside player with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I need `.vtt` subtitles to be at the top of the player (not at the bottom). Is there a way to do it with CSS?

```
<track label="English" kind="subtitles" srcLang="english" src={sample} default />
```

Then I tried to add props to `video::cue` like `position/margin/padding`, but no success:

```
  '&::cue': {
    // these props work fine
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    color: 'white',
  }
```

Comment: Dont see anything about vtt and subtitles

Comment: you could try using css, use the display, position css properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free library, e.g. https://github.com/videojs/video.js where you can easily change the position and other CSS properties.

```css
.vjs-text-track-cue div{
  background-color: green !important;
  font-size: 30px !important;
}
.vjs-text-track-cue{
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/8.3.0/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/8.3.0/video.min.js"></script>
<video id="dotsub_example" class="video-js  vjs-default-skin" width="450" height="193" controls data-setup="[]">
  <source src="https://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/video/sintel-short.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <track
    label="English"
    kind="subtitles"
    srclang="en"
    src="https://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/subtitles/vtt/sintel-de.vtt"
    default />
</video>
```